# Web Application recording gets Fail due to Semi-Colon presence at the end of JSON Form Data of request

Tags: jmeter

Web Application recording gets Fail due to Semi-Colon presence at the end of JSON Form Data of a request.

**Steps :**

1) Set proxy for Web Application.

2) Installed the proper certificate to start the recording for JMeter.

3) Then started the recording.

4) In mid of recording flow, my recording gets stop.

5) When I explored the error then I got an error message in developer mode for respective request :

```
Browser: Chrome
Status Code:
500 Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: =. Path '', line 1, position 4646.
```

6) When I performed the particular step manually on my web application then it was working fine. 
Please help me to resolve this issue. I am not able to complete recording of my Web Application flow.

Comment: Could you show more detail on the failing request/response ? JMeter doesn't add anything. You should compare a working request with a failing one using fiddler for example

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK : Thank You for the response. I have compared the both requests and observed that the extra Colon symbol is there in JSON data of my Web Application. Please check the symbol at the end of following string: 9722acd549fd"}]}:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you configured JMeter for recording using [Recording Template](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions) - update your question with the contents or `recording.xml` file. If not - retry your attempt using the aforementioned Recording Template.

If you don't have the template or don't want to use it add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener as a child of the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and configure it like:

[image: JMeter REcording View Results Tree]

---

Another recording option is using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension), it is non-invasive way of capturing browser requests and converting them into a JMeter test plan, in this case you don't have to worry about

Comment: Thank You Dmitri for your response. I have used the JMeter Chrome Extension to solve my current issue as a work around.